# Convert typescript enums to strings during build / compilation

Tags: typescript

I recently changed from using strings in my types to using enums i.e.

```
export interface Dog {
  size: "SMALL" | "MEDIUM" | "BIG"
}
```

becomes

```
export enum SIZE {
  SMALL = "SMALL",
  MEDIUM = "MEDIUM",
  BIG = "BIG"
}

type Dog {
  size: SIZE
}
```

But this is causing issues in my project now. I have package named `@MyApp/types` that was previously removed from production code when I built my `dist` folder. With enums it is now persisted i.e. this code is included in my `dist`

```
const types_1 = require("@MyApp/types");

// ...

types_1.SIZE.BIG
```

Is there a way to tell typescript compiler to change above to simply be

```
"BIG"
```

So types package is not included into `dist` build?

Comment: Have you looked into a [`const enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it is stated by  @jonsharpe, you can use `const` for enum type creation. See my example:

```
interface Dog {
  size: SIZE
} 

 const enum SIZE {
  SMALL = "SMALL",
  MEDIUM = "MEDIUM",
  BIG = "BIG"
}


var dog:Dog = { size: SIZE.MEDIUM };
```